# Overriding members having Path Dependent types in Scala. Explanation is needed in terms of Scala Language Specification

Tags: scala, types, overriding, path-dependent-type

Consider the following simple Scala experiment:

```
scala> trait A {class C;val c:C}
defined trait A

scala> object O1 extends A {val c=new C}
defined object O1

scala> object O2 extends A {val c=O1.c}
<console>:9: error: overriding value c in trait A of type O2.C;
 value c has incompatible type
       object O2 extends A {val c=O1.c}
```

According to the Scala Language Specification (SLS 5.1.4):

The type of the value `O1.c` should conform to the type of `A.c` because the former overrides the latter.

**Question 1:**

Where in the SLS it is specified the rule from which it follows that the type of `O1.c` indeed does conform to the type of `A.c`?

So why should `object O1 extends A {val c=new C}` compile **according to the SLS** ?

**Question 2:**

Where in the SLS it is specified the rule from which it follows that the type of the value `O1.c` does not conform to the type of the value `O2.c`?

In other words, **from which SLS rule it follows** that `object O2 extends A {val c=O1.c}` should not compile?

Related : why should the type of the value of `O2.c`be `O2.C` according to the SLS ?

**Update**:

What is the type of the value `O1.c` and of the abstract value member `A.c` according to the SLS ?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `A.c` is `A#C`, and `O1.c` (update: of type `O1.C`, which per the SLS is `O1.type#C`) does indeed conform to `A#c`.

Question 1: inside `O1`, the type `C` is `O1.C` and `new C` is `new O1.C` (see the rules for type designators in 3.2.3). `O1.C` conforms to `O1.C` because it is equivalent (because equivalence is a congruence).

Question 2: It follows because `O1` does not conform to `O2`, because none of the rules in 3.5.1 or 3.5.2 would make `O1` conform to `O2`. So the rule for type projections in 3.5.2 doesn't apply.

A constructor invocation returns a value of that type, per 5.1.1.

(I really don't think the specification is the best way to learn these things; better to get a practical sense of how things work first).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The problem is that there is still a huge gap between the Specification and pretty much any other Scala book. The Specification is indeed very difficult to read but in cases like this no Scala book written for mere mortals seems to help.

Comment: Where do I said that `A.c` is a type?

Comment: SLS 3.2.2 : "A type projection T#x references the type member named x of type T." So `A#c` is not valid in this case because `c` is not a type member, so `A#c` is meaningless in this context. Could someone please comment on this?