# Type selection, type projection. What is S#T in Scala ? Scala Language Specification based explanation is needed

Tags: scala, types

In SLS 3.4 it is written : "The definition of a type projection S#T is the member binding dT of the type T in S".

I have read SLS 3.4 already 10 times but I still don't get it what `S#T` is and what kind of values have this type.

What does `S#T` mean ?

What is a member binding ?

What is a base type ?

More specifically: why is it true that if

```
class A
{ 
   class B
}
```

then `A#B` refers to the any instance of the inner class `B` ?

How can this statement be derived from SLS section 3.4 ?

I think that is where the answer is, but the SLS is very difficult to understand.

This question is a spin-off of this question : [Overriding members having Path Dependent types in Scala. Explanation is needed in terms of Scala Language Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840363/overriding-members-having-path-dependent-types-in-scala-explanation-is-needed-i) .

Understanding what `S#T` really is is a pre-requisit for being able to find an answer for [Overriding members having Path Dependent types in Scala. Explanation is needed in terms of Scala Language Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840363/overriding-members-having-path-dependent-types-in-scala-explanation-is-needed-i).

**Reason for asking:**

The SLS is very difficult to read for mere mortals. With this question I try to help mere mortals (including myself) who would like to get some understanding of the SLS.

The SLS does not seem to be explained anywhere in detail, there is a gap between Scala books for mere mortals and SLS. With this question I try to make a narrow bridge over this gap.

**In Odersky's book it is written:**

[image]

Where he writes:

> Both of these types conform to (are subtypes of) the more general type
>   Outer#Inner, which represents the Inner class with an arbi- trary
>   outer object of type Outer.

**Final question:**

The question is, how can this statement be justified by the SLS ?

How can this statement be "derived" from the SLS ?

In order to be able to answer this last question, one has to understand what S#T really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a legalistic understanding of `A#B` (only a practical one) so I can't help with the first part, but I can answer your final question: per 3.2.3, the type `o1.Inner` is `o1.type#Inner`. Per 3.5.2, "A type projection `T#t` conforms to `U#t` if `T` conforms to `U`". Hopefully it's obvious that `o1.type <: Outer`; strictly this is because (again in 3.5.2) "A singleton type `p.type` conforms to the type of the path `p`".